# NetBeans 6.5.1 fails installation on Mac OS X 10.8.4 Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, netbeans

I am trying to install NetBeans 6.5.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.4 but it keeps giving me this error:

[image]

The image is not mine but it's the same error.

## What I've done so far:

1. Installed java developer package through developer.apple.com.

This is my output from java -version:

> - $java -version
>
> - java version "1.6.0_65"
>
> - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
>
> - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

2. chown the NetBeans .dmg file to user:admin
3. Confirmed the md5 checksum for the .dmg file
4. Created the environment variable `$JAVA_HOME` giving me the following output:

> - $ echo $JAVA_HOME
>
> - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Home

---

And now my **/var/log/install.log** file referring to the error:

```
Feb 16 16:07:42 MacBook-Pro-de-david.local installd[4526]: PackageKit: allow user idle system sleep

Feb 16 16:07:42 MacBook-Pro-de-david.local installd[4526]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the $

            NSFilePath = "./postflight";
            NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cbaseide.pkg\U201d.";
            NSURL = "file://localhost/Volumes/NetBeans%206.5.1/NetBeans%206.5.1.mpkg/Contents/Packages/baseide.pkg";
            PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "org.netbeans.ide";
        }

Feb 16 16:07:42 MacBook-Pro-de-david.local Installer[4514]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the pa$

Feb 16 16:07:42 MacBook-Pro-de-david.local Installer[4514]: Install failed: Ocorreu um erro desconhecido no Instalador, que impediu a instalação. Caso necessite de assistência, con$

Feb 16 16:07:42 MacBook-Pro-de-david.local Installer[4514]: IFDInstallController E2C36220 state = 7

Feb 16 16:07:42 MacBook-Pro-de-david.local Installer[4514]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.

Feb 16 16:07:42 MacBook-Pro-de-david.local Installer[4514]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'Ocorreu um erro desconhecido no Instalador, que impediu a instalação. Caso necess$
```

---

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you all for reading and if you can help I would appreciate it